# Flutter golden tests capture empty screenshots

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm trying to get Flutter golden tests to work, for example:

```
testWidgets('Golden test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final widget = Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child:  Text('foo'),
    );
    await tester.pumpWidget(widget);
    await expectLater(find.byType(Text), matchesGoldenFile('golden.png'));
  });
```

However, the captured screenshot is just a white rectangle on a transparent background: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm1E5.png

I've also tried putting it inside a `Material`, and a few other things, but none have actually rendered the widget in a way you might expect on a device.

I'm working on OS X, Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Flutter golden tests do not load fonts, but you may be able to get them like this . . .

```dart
await loadAppFonts();
```

Checkout [golden_toolkit: loading fonts](https://pub.dev/packages/golden_toolkit#loading-fonts) for details.

Comment: Fantastic library, works a treat, thanks for the pointer.